# Slow closing SqlSession in myBatis with spring

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have a trouble with myBatis. I see serious performance degradation on transactional methods (And even non transactional) after enabling transaction manager in spring:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.company.model" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.company.mapper" />

</bean>
```

Log for example, as you can see there are about 150 milliseconds between closing and starting new transaction.

```
09:28:58.134 [http-bio-9081-exec-12] DEBUG o.m.s.SqlSessionUtils - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@cf80c3]
09:28:58.297 [http-bio-9081-exec-3] DEBUG o.m.s.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
```

Database: Oracle 11.2
Thanks.

Comment: You're using a BasicDataSource. I would look at connection pooling if you're worried about performance. There are different libraries that can help with this, this article explains using c3p0 but it might be a bit out of date. Should give you the idea though. http://www.raistudies.com/spring/integrating-mybatis-3-and-spring-frameworks-part-2/

Comment: I have switched on BoneCP as pooled datasource, but mybatis whatever call selects sequentualy with big delay between transactions.

Comment: I wouldn't call 150ms a big delay. How many transactions are you using per request? If you had a separate transaction for every select then the 150ms might start adding up but you should probably combine them into one transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was stupid. It was database degradation.